# Browser ends PHP infinite loops and then prints the data

Tags: php, loops, browser, for-loop

I am trying to capture live feeds from a card reader and printing it using PHP.

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        $subdata=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
        $subdata2=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedatatemp.txt");

        if($subdata!=$subdata2)
        {
            copy("/home/openflow/subscribedatatemp.txt","/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
            $sub=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
            $i++;
            echo "\n". $i."--".$sub;
        }
    }
?>
```

I am using the for loop as an infinite loop. Whenever there is new data, my card reader script writes it into the **subscribedatatemp.txt** file and the above script checks for a difference between **subscribedatatemp.txt** (the latest entry) and **subscribedata.txt** (the previous entry). If there's a difference, it should copy the latest onto the previous and echo the latest data.

The problem is when I am executing the PHP code above, it doesn't show anything for a while and after sometime the browser stops loading and displays all the data that it got in the loading time.

This indicates that the loop execution is getting stopped and all the data is being printed after the end of the while loop, right? How can I correct this?

Comment: Your script is probably timing out, try adding `set_time_limit(0)` to the top

Comment: where should i add that? I am new to php and am not sure where to add the line. can you please tell me where to add it?

Comment: `<?php set_time_limit(0) ... ?>`. Also you should try to avoid running "tight" loops that don't give other processes the chance to get some CPU time. Introduce a `sleep(50)` or `sleep(100)` before the end of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your code, add this line:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

So your whole code looks like this:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$i=0;
for(;;)
{
$subdata=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
$subdata2=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedatatemp.txt");

if($subdata!=$subdata2)
{
copy("/home/openflow/subscribedatatemp.txt","/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
$sub=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
$i++;
echo "\n". $i."--".$sub;
}
}
?>
```

Read more on `set_time_limit()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Also, check if `max_execution_time` in your `php.ini` file is not set.

Comment: i tried the same thing and the data wouldn't be echoed until the execution ends.. it shouldn't be that way right?

Whenever there's a chenge, there should be an echo.. @imulsion

Comment: Make sure you've disabled output buffering (ini setting `output_buffering`) -- see more http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to prevent your script from timing out by passing in a `0` at the beginning of the script to make it an infinite wait.

You also want to add a [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) to your loop so it doesn't consume all of your CPU cycles.

Finally you will need to add a [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) at the end of each loop to empty the buffer and send it to the client.

```
<?php
// set an infinite timeout
set_time_limit(0);
// create an infinite loop
while (true) {
    // do your logic here
    $subdata=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
    $subdata2=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedatatemp.txt");
    // .... etc.

    // flush buffer to the client
    flush();

    // go to sleep to give the CPU a break
    sleep(100);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to display output after each loop (instead of waiting for the whole script to end), so to echo(`flush`) each loop, you'll need to add `flush()` at the end of the loop.

Also we'll add `set_time_limit(0)` before the loop, so our script takes it time to execute.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ob_end_flush();


$i=0;
for(;;)
{
$subdata=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
$subdata2=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedatatemp.txt");

if($subdata!=$subdata2)
{
copy("/home/openflow/subscribedatatemp.txt","/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
$sub=file_get_contents("/home/openflow/subscribedata.txt");
$i++;
echo "\n". $i."--".$sub;
/*flush()*/
}

}
ob_start();
?>
```

Comment: nope.. that's not even showing any kind of data.. adding flush isn't getting me any data.. and if i remove time limit and run the script too... the output i got previously isn't displayed.. am just getting a blank screen

Comment: i am getting the same blank screen again after a while :|

Answer (score 0):

use `flush` and `sleep` functions at the end of your loop...

but it would be better to use ajax call for this..